# Incorrect toll total cost while calculating route in Brazil

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to get the toll cost estimation using **here-api**, but the toll cost I'm getting in response is incorrect.

I'm trying this request.

> https://tce.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id=XXXXXXX&app_code=XXXXXXXX&waypoint0=-23.5631394,-46.6532152&waypoint1=-23.5248497,-46.1924423&mode=fastest;car&cost_optimize=0&tollVehicleType=2&currency=BRL

```
Response: costs: { totalCost: "5.55", currency: "BRL", details: { driverCost: "0.0", vehicleCost: "0.0", tollCost: "5.55" } }
```

The real toll cost for this request is 3.70 BRL.

Comment: Is it possible to point out not correct location of toll cost or link?

Comment: Sure, this is the location. https://www.google.com/search?q=ped%C3%A1gio%20ayrton%20senna%20itaquaquecetuba&oq=ped%C3%A1gio+ayrton+senna+it&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.7511j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=-23466637,-46362626,662&tbm=lcl&rldimm=6223766587251390385&ved=2ahUKEwizpu3j0OPhAhUPK7kGHY80DUkQvS4wAHoECAoQIQ&rldoc=1&tbs=lrf:!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:2#rlfi=hd:;si:6223766587251390385;mv:!1m2!1d-23.3735671!2d-46.123781900000004!2m2!1d-23.5707557!2d-46.6868829;tbs:lrf:!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:2

Comment: We reported this issue internally and take a look at it to fix. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The fixed toll cost value was updated already in the system, it will be refreshed soon.